# How to implement different properties of the droppable for each draggable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I apologize if the question is formulated sloppy. 
I'm just somewhere in the beginning of understanding jquery.

I want to implement a form builder based on drag and drop.

Process has already started, did what I wanted for a single element:

jsfiddle.net/z7sxxhe4

The main question - how to do so that every element of the left column after dragging "converted" to another element.

For example, I drag the first button - it turns into a form. Drag the second - it turns into a table, etc.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your drop function it gives you ui which contains the element you dragged and dropped. So you would check what kind of element it is or the id, name, etc. and use conditionals based on that to determine what kind of element to add.

Example:

```
drop: function (e, ui) {
  if (ui.draggable[0].id == "auth") {
      var $field = '<div class="input-block"><span class="label label-primary">'+          ui.draggable.text() +'</span><input type="text" class="form-control main-input" placeholder="Your text"></div>';
      var $el = $($field);
      $el.append($('<div class="removeqwe"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>').click(function () {    $(this).parent().detach(); }));
      $(this).append($el);
  }
  else if (ui.draggable[0].id == "second") {
       ....
  }
  else if (ui.draggable[0].id == "third") {
       ....
  }
  else if (ui.draggable[0].id == "fourth") {
       ....
  }  
}
```

Comment: This would work, but is not really dynamic. E.g. when you add a new type you have to alter the javascript too.

Comment: @user3153169, yeah, maybe you're right, but for now this solution is more understandable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked filters">
    <li class="active" id="auth" data-type="form"><a href="#">Auth</a></li>
    <li class="active" id="second" data-type="table"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
    <li class="active" id="third" data-type="button"><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    <li class="active" id="fourth" data-type="div"><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
</ul>


drop: function (e, ui) {
    var $field = "<" + ui.draggable.data("type") + " " + // the rest
}
```

Better would be something like:

```
drop: function (e, ui) {
    var $element = $("<" + ui.draggable.data("type") + ">");
    $element.addClass("someClass");
}
```

Comment: thanks, good idea, but can you please explain me more? like what does "<" that mean?

Comment: The "<" is for the opening tag of the element, e.g. `$("<" + "div" + ">")`

Comment: decided to use your solution, but still don't understand how to define which element is dropped?

Comment: Depending on what element you define in the `data-type="element"` will create the corresponding element. E.g. if `data-type="button"` the function will create `$("<" + "button" + ">")`, which will result in a jQuery button DOM element.